# Why does my #define macro appear to be a global?

Tags: c, gcc

I was investigating a compile and link issue within my program when I came across the following macro that was defined in a header and source file:

```
/* file_A.c */
#ifndef _NVSize    
   #define _NVSize 1
#endif

/* file_B.c */
#include "My_Header.h"
#ifndef _NVSize    
   #define _NVSize 1
#endif

/* My_Header.h */
#define _NVSize 1024
```

Nothing out of the ordinary yet, until I saw the following information in the GCC output map file:

```
/* My Map File */
...
.rodata  0x08015694   _NVSize
...
```

My understanding of the map file is that if you see a symbol in the .rodata section of the map file, this symbol is being treated as a global variable by the compiler.  But, this shouldn't be the case because macros should be handled by the preprocessor before the compiler even parses the file.  This macro should be replaced with it's defined value before compiling.

Is this the standard way that GCC handles macros or is there some implementation specific reason that GCC would treat this as a global (debug setting maybe)?  Also, what does this mean if my macro gets redefined in a different source file?  Did I just redefine it for a single source file or did I modify a global variable, thereby changing _NVSize everywhere it's used within my program?

Comment: Does that also occur when compiling with optimizations/without debugging?

Comment: The compiler settings for the file are -O1 -MD -ggdb ...

Comment: I'm not seeing any linker settings in the build output, I'm going to have to dig this up.

Comment: Try changing the name of the macro to `_NVSize`. The compiler or library might be using that name for its own purposes, which it's allowed to do since it's a reserved name.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what `.rodata is` (presumably it refers to read-only data), but when I generate a linker map I see things like `.rodata        0x00000000080484c8       0x15 /tmp/ccBsVv1p.o`.  It looks like the first argument is an address and the second is a value stored at that address.  Perhaps the linker is being "helpful" by using the symbolic name you've provided.  Try narrowing down your test case to a *small* example that exhibits the system, and look at *all* occurrences of `_NVSize` in the map file.  In any case, you shouldn't be using that identifier yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the compiler is free to assign your macro to a global variable *as long as it ensures that this produces the exact same result* as if it did a textual replacement.

During the compilation the compiler can mark this global specially to denote that it is a macro constant value, so no re-assignment is possible, no address can be taken, etc.

If you redefine the macro in your sorce, the compiler might not perform this transformation (and treat it as you'd expect: a pre-compier textual replacement), perform it on one of the different values (or on all of them say, using different names for each occurrance), or do domething else :)

Comment: I'm going to have to test this to see what values are actually being used in file_A and file_B.  But looking at the sample code, _NVSize SHOULD equal 1 for file_A, and _NVSize SHOULD be 1024 for file_B - do you agree?

Comment: @BryanC. - yes, that's what the standard requires (from the point of the code).   But note that ultimately what matters is whether during execution the program produces the desired (i.e. standard mandated) result or not, which depends on how your compiler is actually using the _NVSize value

Comment: "I think the compiler is free to assign your macro to a global variable" Any citation for this? Cos I'm very curious to know how the macro escaped the pre-processor replacement?

Comment: @PavanManjunath - I cannot give you citation for my thoughts :)  But I cannot see why a compiler could not do this if the output is indistinguishable from what the standard requires the program to do.  I am not familiar with how gcc works, but a (hypothetical) compiler could integrate with the preprocessor and perform optimizations that is not what you expect from the usual preprocessor way -- e.g. if there is no output of the preprocessed file.  I'm sure if you ask the compiler to output the preprocessed file it will give you what you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are substituted in the preprocessor step, the compiler only sees the substituted result. Thus if it sees the macro name, then my bet is that the macro wasn't defined at the point of usage. It is defined between the specific `#define _NVSize` and an `#undef _NVSize`. Redefining an existing macro without using an `#undef` first should result in a preprocessor error, AFAIR.

BTW, you shouldn't start your macro names with an underscore. These are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Redefinition results in "stacking" the values. The old value can be reinstalled by an `#undef`. Redefinition may (should?) issue a warning, however.

Comment: Huh? I don't know about what language or what C extension you're talking, but standard C doesn't allow stacking of definitions. An existing macro can be redefined when both definitions are the same, e.g. allowing to define the same macro in different header files. See 6.10.3.2 in the standard.

Comment: You are right. I must have been confused by a compiler I used years ago. I never used the mechanism anyway. too dangerous.